# Finding files in multiple directories using CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd, wildcard

I am trying to figure out the best way to find all the files listed in specific directories. This is my issue:

In Directory1 there are a bunch of directories like SubDir1, SubDir2, SubDir3, etc... I need to find all the .txt files in the sub directories while being in Directory1 with one command all at once. I am assuming it would be some kind of wildcard operator that would do the trick but I have also been known to be wrong in the past...

**EDIT:**

Knowing that:

```
dir \*.txt /s
```

would access all of the files, what would be the best way to copy all of them to a folder called "test" the same way?

Thank you!

Comment: As in `dir c:\directory1\*.txt /s` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @npocmaka and @DavidRuhmann this is what worked for me:

```
for /f "delims=" %F in ('dir \*.txt /s/b') do copy "%~F" "C:\test\" /Y
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir \*.txt /s /b') do copy "%%~F" "c:\test\" /Y
```

Comment: I tried using what you put and it returned with an error saying "%%F was unexpected at this time".

Comment: @jpriff If running from the command line, use single `%` signs, double `%%` percent signs are for batch files.

Comment: @DavidRuhmann was messing around with it just before commented and saw that the error disappeared with the single `%`. I am now having an issue with actually copying the files over. It seems to be reading them from the first directory fine, but it wont actually copy anything over. It says `total files listed: my\directory\path\` then `0 files copied`.